# Viewing events in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I know how to add code for custom events in Google Analytics—`_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'some button'])`—but how do I view these events?

If it's Home -> Intelligence events -> overview, could anyone confirm if events are supposed to be real-time? Do they appear every 24 hours?

### Update

Because _trackEvent doesn't appear on the admin dashboard immediately like _trackPageview I've fallen back to using the following event wrapper for _trackPageview:

```
window.gaEvent = function gaEvent(event_name){
  event_name = event_name.replace(/\s/gi, '_');
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', event_name]);
};
//super easy to use:
gaEvent('Application action');
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On the left-hand menu, Behavior->Events

Comment: how fast are they supposed to appear?

Comment: I have real-time page views working, but nothing for events

Comment: On the bottom right of events pages it says when the event report was produced and gives a link to refresh it. I don't know for definite the delay, I'd say not real time, more like 20-30 minutes, but that's the general feeling I've had rather than something factual.